# Calculating width of Tabs in TabControl (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I've been looking everywhere and it's bugging me because it looks like I'm the only one who has asked this before. How do you calculate the widths of a Tab in the Windows Forms `TabControl`?

Each Tab that gets opened or created in my app will be of variable length and the Font and Font Size used in these tabs may also change at runtime.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve this one myself by looking in the [intellisense](/questions/tagged/intellisense) list a bit more. The `TabControl.GetTabRect()` method returns a Rectangle for the tab:

```
Rectangle rect = this.tabControl1.GetTabRect(tabControl1.SelectedIndex);
MessageBox.Show(rect.Width.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it using the `ItemSize` Property of the `TabControl`.

If you want the same width for all the tabs then use the following,

```
this.tabControl1.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
```